# Wordpress Gravity Form send to third party(Sendgrid API)

Tags: wordpress, api, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms, sendgrid-api-v3

I've been trying to add emails from my wordpress site to sendgrid fro campaign, I have looked on to the documentation of Sendgrid but the only thing that works from Gravity form to Sendgrid is adding list though the use of this endpoint: https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists

What I want is to use this endpoint: https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/{list_id}/recipients/{recipient_id} 
to add a new contact in sengrid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [gform_after_submission](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/#3-send-entry-data-to-third-party) hook to send data to a third party endpoint.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, I don't want the data to be submitted directly to a third during the submission of the form, what I want is let the admin to process the entries. In this part I'm having in finding what method should I used in processing the entries.